# CockroachDB performance is much worse than mongoDB and Aurora?

Tags: database, performance, load-testing, cockroachdb

I am doing some basic load testing against cockroachDB, mongoDB and Aurora. I just have a project which can keep read/write into one of those three DBs. In that project, we can configure groutine numbers about read/write so that we can mimic different test scenarios: read-heavy, write-heavy, balanced.

The result shows cockroachDB's performance is terrible compared to another two. I don't expected cockroachDB performance is that bad. Wondering some tricky settings may be needed to be configured for cockroachDB. Any suggestions? Thanks forks!

[image]

Balanced traffic: 500 write: 500 read. This is the avg operation per second:

- Mongo_read: 44.6k/s
- Aurora_read: 33.6k/s
- Aurora_insert: 14.3k/s
- Mongo_insert: 2.6k/s
- Crdb_insert: 2.6k/s
- Crdb_read: 2.3k/s

Heavy write traffic: 1000 write: 100 read. This is the avg operation per second:

- Aurora_read: 40.5k/s
- Aurora_insert: 10.5k/s
- Mongo_insert: 10.4k/s
- Mongo_read: 10.2k/s
- Crdb_insert: 3.8k/s
- Crdb_read: 0.6k/s

Heavy write traffic: 100 write: 1000 read. This is the avg operation per second:

- Aurora_read: 69.8k/s
- Mongo_read: 46.7k/s
- Crdb_read: 8k/s
- Aurora_insert: 7k/s
- Mongo_insert: 0.8k/s
- Crdb_insert: 0.7k/s

Comment: not sure what benchmark you do, but ~2 years ago i did similar thing locally using docker (all 3 instance writing to same disk, so it should be bottleneck on the disk side), it got like ~8K rps insert, 1,2K rps update, 38K rps select (cockroachdb version 21.1.11) the link here: http://kokizzu.blogspot.com/2021/11/databases-with-automatic-rebalance.html